# Full text query in Amazon Athena is timing-out when using `LIKE`

Tags: amazon-web-services, presto, amazon-athena

Getting timeout error for a full text query in Athena like this...

```
SELECT count(textbody) FROM "email"."some_table" where textbody like '% some text to seach%'
```

Is there any way to optimize it?

---

Update:

The create table statement:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `email`.`email5_newsletters_04032019`(
`nesletterid` string,
`name` string,
`format` string,
`subject` string,
`textbody` string,
`htmlbody` string,
`createdate` string,
`active` string,
`archive` string,
`ownerid` string
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
'serialization.format' = ',',
'field.delim' = ',',
'ESCAPED BY' = '\\'
) LOCATION 's3://some_bucket/email_backup_updated/email5/'
TBLPROPERTIES ('has_encrypted_data'='false');
```

And S3 bucket contents:

```
# aws s3 ls s3://xxx/email_backup_updated/email5/ --human
2020-08-22 15:34:44    2.2 GiB email_newsletters_04032019_updated.csv.gz
```

---

There are 11 million records in this file. The file can be imported within 30 minutes in Redshift and everything works OK in redshift. I will prefer to use Athena!

Comment: What is the average file size in source and file format used?

Comment: How many rows are in the table? What is file format? Is the data compressed? How big is the `email` field? Using `LIKE` is very inefficient because Athena needs to check every row and look through the entire field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSV is not a format that integrates very well with the presto engine, as queries need to read the full row to reach a single column. A way to optimize usage of athena, which will also save you plenty of storage costs, is to switch to a columnar storage format, like parquet or orc, and you can actually do it with a query:

```
CREATE TABLE `email`.`email5_newsletters_04032019_orc`
WITH (
      external_location = 's3://my_orc_table/',
      format = 'ORC')
AS SELECT * 
FROM `email`.`email5_newsletters_04032019`;
```

Then rerun your query above on the new table:

```
SELECT count(textbody) FROM "email"."email5_newsletters_04032019_orc" where textbody like '% some text to seach%'
```

Comment: How do I add more data to this table? I usually get updates every month.

Comment: You can do an `insert into` like so: 
```INSERT INTO destination_table 
SELECT select_query 
FROM source_table_or_view
```, see full doc: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/insert-into.html